# How to get a function pointer (in order to get function address at runtime) in llvm

Tags: llvm, function-pointers

In C or C++, I can get the address of function func_1 at run time with the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void func_1()
{
    printf("this is func_1\n");
}

int main()
{   
    printf("this is main\n");
    func_1();
    void *addr = (void*)func_1; // get the addr of func_1
    return 0;
}
```

When I convert this code to IR, I can see that the corresponding statement to get the address of the function is:

```
  store i8* bitcast (void ()* @func_1 to i8*), i8** %addr, align 8
  %2 = load i8*, i8** %addr, align 8
  %call1 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([18 x i8], [18 x i8]* @.str.3, i64 0, i64 0), i8* %2)
```

Now, I want to use the LLVM compiler to use the pass optimization phase to add one such instruction for each function in the target program to get the function address. How do I achieve this? Maybe a storeInst and a loadInst, but how to set the parameters? In particular, void ()* @func_1 to i8*

Comment: Only the `StoreInst` is needed. That has two components, the value stored and the pointer to the address where the value is stored. The value is a [constant cast](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1ConstantExpr.html#a1f469b1f703519ae25ce564c8704310f) from the function's address to `i8*`, the pointer is called `%addr`. You just need to make one such `StoreInst` per function. (Your other two lines are related to the printf.)

Comment: The `bitcast (void ()* @func_1 to i8*)` is an llvm::ConstantExpr. You can use a constant expression or an instruction to do the bitcast. `@func` already is a pointer to function (in this case `void ()*` meaning pointer-to-function-that-takes-no-arguments-and-returns-void), but if you don't like the type you may bitcast it to something else, which clang does when you store it in a `void *` (and not a `typedef void (*fptr)(void); fptr *addr = &func_1;`

Comment: "`@func` already is a pointer to function" meaning if you have llvm::Function \*my_value = M.getFunction("func_1") then `my_value` is an llvm::Value\* which you can plug into a StoreInst or a BitCastInst directly. It is the pointer to the function, usable as a value in the IR.